# arguments to tuple are copied instead of moved when returning the tuple from a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, visual-studio-2017, move-semantics

I have a question about the following code. My compiler is **MSVC++ 17 Visual studio version 15.3** with compiler option /std:c++14 (as opposed to /std:c++latest) running in **release mode**:

```
struct Bar
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    Bar() { std::cout << "default\n";  }
    Bar(int a, const std::string& b)    : a{ a }, b{ b } { std::cout << "direct\n"; }
    Bar(int a, std::string&& b)         : a{ a }, b{ std::move(b) } { std::cout << "direct move b\n"; }
    Bar(const Bar& other)               : a{ other.a }, b{ other.b } { std::cout << "const copy\n"; }
    Bar(Bar&& other)                    : a{ std::move(other.a) }, b{ std::move(other.b) } { std::cout << "move\n"; }
    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
        std::cout << "const assign\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Bar& operator=(Bar&& other)
    {
        a = std::move(other.a); //would this even be correct?
        b = std::move(other.b); 
        std::cout << "move assign\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

std::tuple<Bar, Bar> foo()
{
    std::string s = "dsdf";
    return { { 1, s }, { 5, "asdf" } };
}

int main()
{
    Bar a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = foo();
    std::cout << a.a << a.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a << b.b;
}
```

The output is:

```
default
default
direct
direct move b
const copy <-- Why copy? Why not move>
const copy <-- Why copy? Why not move>
move assign
move assign
1dsdf
5asdf
```

If I change `return { { 1, s }, { 5, "asdf" } };` to `return { Bar{ 1, s }, Bar{ 5, "asdf" } };` the output changes to:

```
default
default
direct
direct move b
move
move
move assign
move assign
1dsdf
5asdf
```

**Question:** Why isn't a move performed in both cases? Why is the copy constructor called in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest distillation of your question is why:

```
std::tuple<Bar> t{{5, "asdf"}};
```

prints

```
direct move b
const copy
```

but

```
std::tuple<Bar> u{Bar{5, "asdf"}};
```

prints

```
direct move b
move
```

To answer that question, we have to determine what those two declarations actually do. And in order to do that, we have to understand which of [`std::tuple`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) get called. The relevant ones are (neither the `explicit`ness and `constexpr`ness of each constructor is relevant, so I am omitting them for brevity):

```
tuple( const Types&... args ); // (2)

template< class... UTypes >
tuple( UTypes&&... args );     // (3)
```

Initializing with `Bar{5, "asdf"}` would invoke constructor `(3)` as the better match (both `(2)` and `(3)` are viable, but we get a less cv-qualified reference in `(3)`), which would forward from the `UTypes` into the `tuple`. This is why we end up with `move`.

But initializing with just `{5, "asdf"}`, this constructor isn't viable because *braced-init-list*s have no type that can be deduced. Hence our *only* option is `(2)`, and we end up with a copy.

The only way to fix this would be to add non-template constructors that take rvalue references to each of the `Types`. But you would need `2^N-1` such constructors (all but the one that takes all const lvalue references - since that one could be deduced), so instead we end up with a design that works in all cases but is suboptimal. But since you could just specify the type you want on the call site, this isn't a huge defect.